# How to resolve jquery popup issue?

Tags: apex, trigger, javascript, custom-button, jquery

When i click on custom button called Request for warranty as admin the Jquery popup is fine.[image]

But when i click on same button as partner (logged into partner user) the jquery message is like transparent message with no styles and all like below:

[image]

Same code but why for partner users it is population like this please find custom button code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js")}

{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js')}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT('/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js')}

function appendScript1(msg) {
    //Append JQuery CSS 
    var head = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var v_css = window.parent.document.createElement('link');
    v_css.rel = 'stylesheet';
    v_css.type = 'text/css';
    //Use jQuery UI custom theme from Static Resource 
    if (n == null) {
        v_css.href = '/resource/' + '{!LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),': ','
        '),' - ','
        '),'
        ','
        '),10)}' + '/jqueryResources/jqueryui.css';
    } else {
        v_css.href = '/cpp/resource/' + '{!LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),': ','
        '),' - ','
        '),'
        ','
        '),10)}' + '/jqueryResources/jqueryui.css';
    }
    head.appendChild(v_css);

    interval = self.setInterval(function() {
        //Check to see if jQuery has loaded 
        if (jQuery) {
            //if jQuery has loaded, clear the interval 
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            //create a div in the body which we will use for our dialog. 
            $(window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).append("<div id=infoNotice title='' ></div>");
            //Disable scrolling 
            $('body', window.parent.document).addClass('stop-scrolling');
            //Execute checking of authorization 

            $('#infoNotice', window.parent.document).html("<p><div style='margin: 20px;'><table><tr><td valign='top'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 0;'></span></td><td>" + msg + "</td></tr></table></div></p>");
            showdialog1();
        }
    }, 300);
}

function showdialog1() {
    //Bind enabling of scrolling 
    $('#infoNotice', window.parent.document).bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
        $('body', window.parent.document).removeClass('stop-scrolling');
    });
    //Open created Div as a Jquery Dialog box for Error Messages 
    $("#infoNotice", window.parent.document).dialog({
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
}

//appendScript1(); 

var result = sforce.apex.execute('PreventWarranty', 'warranty', {
    oppid: '{!Opportunity.Id}'
});
if (result == 'Please check Renewal date') {
    var msg = '{!$Label.Prevent_Warranty_Label}';
    appendScript1(msg);
} else {

    var x = top.window.location.href;
    var n = x.match('cpp');
    var oppId = '{!Opportunity.Id}';
    var pageurl;
    if (n == null) {


        loadScript('/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js');
        loadScript('/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js');
        //loadScript('/resource/jqueryResources/jquery.js'); 
        //loadScript('/resource/jqueryResources/jquery-ui.js'); 
        pageurl = '{!$Label.Org_Instance_Base_URL}/apex/CSRequestWarranty?oppid=' + oppId;
    } else {
        loadScript('/cpp/soap/ajax/31.0/connection.js');
        loadScript('/cpp/soap/ajax/31.0/apex.js');
        //loadScript('/cpp/resource/jqueryResources/jquery.js'); 
        //loadScript('/cpp/resource/jqueryResources/jquery-ui.js'); 

        pageurl = '/cpp/apex/CSRequestWarranty?oppid=' + oppId;
    }

    var interval;

    function appendScript() {
        //Append JQuery CSS 
        var head = window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        var v_css = window.parent.document.createElement('link');
        v_css.rel = 'stylesheet';
        v_css.type = 'text/css';
        //Use jQuery UI custom theme from Static Resource 
        if (n == null) {
            v_css.href = '/resource/' + '{!LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),': ','
            '),' - ','
            '),'
            ','
            '),10)}' + '/jqueryResources/jqueryui.css';
        } else {
            v_css.href = '/cpp/resource/' + '{!LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(NOW()),': ','
            '),' - ','
            '),'
            ','
            '),10)}' + '/jqueryResources/jqueryui.css';
        }
        head.appendChild(v_css);

        interval = self.setInterval(function() {
            //Check to see if jQuery has loaded 
            if (jQuery) {
                //if jQuery has loaded, clear the interval 
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                //create a div in the body which we will use for our dialog. 
                $(window.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).append("<div id=infoNotice title='' ></div>");
                //Disable scrolling 
                $('body', window.parent.document).addClass('stop-scrolling');
                //Execute checking of authorization 
                var res = sforce.apex.execute("CSRequestWarrantyCX", "checkAuthorization", {
                    recID: oppId
                });
                if (res != '') {
                    $('#infoNotice', window.parent.document).html("<p><div style='margin: 20px;'><table><tr><td valign='top'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-alert' style='float: left; margin: 0px 7px 0px 0;'></span></td><td>" + res + "</td></tr></table></div></p>");
                    showdialog();
                } else {
                    window.open(pageurl, '_top');
                }

            }
        }, 300);
    }

    function showdialog() {
        //Bind enabling of scrolling 
        $('#infoNotice', window.parent.document).bind('dialogclose', function(event) {
            $('body', window.parent.document).removeClass('stop-scrolling');
        });
        //Open created Div as a Jquery Dialog box for Error Messages 
        $("#infoNotice", window.parent.document).dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: false,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    appendScript();

    function getURLParameter(name) {
        return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(top.window.location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
    }

    function loadScript(url) {
        var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            if (!request) {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
        }
        var se = document.createElement('script');
        se.type = "text/javascript";
        request.open("GET", url, false);
        request.send(null);
        se.text = request.responseText;
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(se);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you make sure all the `Static Resource` files you append are set to `Public`? Also open up the console and see if you get any error messages.

Comment: Why are you not using URLFOR to link to the static resource. Try changing the /resource/ stuff to refactor to use `{!URLFOR($Resource.xxx, [path to file])}`